# Word in string exists but not recognized

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that contains a column that has a description, I used the following code to extract specific words and create:

```
def criteria (df):
    if df.DESCRIPCION.find('CORONITA')>0:
        return ('Corona')
    else:
        return ('Otras')
df['Marca'] = df.apply(criteria, axis=1)
```

[image]

As you can see, the word exists, but pandas applies 'Otras' instead of Corona.

Any advice?

Comment: Try ">= 0" instead of "> 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` command usually returns an index for location. This location can start at 0. So try changing:

```
if df.DESCRIPCION.find('CORONITA')>0:
```

to:

```
if df.DESCRIPCION.find('CORONITA')>=0:
#                                  ^
```

That should help.  Location `0` means it finds it right at the beginning, which is probably what's happening for you. So, since you exclude `0` as a viable answer, you are getting an incorrect result.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly!